# what's the right way to multiple sp.eye by a scalar symbol

Tags: python, sympy

I tried

```
import sympy as sp

λ = sp.symbols("λ")

λ * sp.eye
```

but seeing error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-dc4fb0b9f400> in <module>
      3 λ = sp.symbols("λ")
      4 
----> 5 λ * sp.eye

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Symbol' and 'function'
```

What's the right way to multiple `sp.eye` by a scalar symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell it how large the identity matrix is!

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols("x")
>>> x * eye(3)
Matrix([
[x, 0, 0],
[0, x, 0],
[0, 0, x]])
```

The problem is that `eye` is a Python function, so you cannot directly multiply it

```py
>>> type(eye)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(eye(3))
<class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'>
```